# line tool photoshop not getting the dotted propertie

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

I'm trying to change a line created with the line tool into a dotted line but I can't find the property for that. I've tried resetting the line tool but I still don't get the option. At the moment it looks like this.

[image]

Instead of this

[image]

Comment: Looks like your PS version is too old to have this feature. I believe it was CS6 that introduced the stroke and its options. One way to get around that in older versions is to use Type tool on a Path and use like period: `.` or dash: `-`. another would be to use illustrator and copy paste it back to Photoshop..

Answer (score 0):

For old Photoshop versions there are many ways to get a dotted line.

- With a Rectangle Shape, working in an empty Layer, add a Stroke with a spaced Brush
- Mask the visible part of this rectangle

[image: dotted line]

- Or create a line with the Pen Tool in an empty layer, add a Stroke to this path with a spaced Brush

[image]